# Running JUnit with both Spring and Parameterized

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have certain integration tests that require the Spring context and will benefit greatly from parameterized testing (will remove lots of duplicate code). I currently have the test running with the class annotation

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)

and I load up the Spring context with

```
@ClassRule
public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

@Rule
public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

The above works, but to be frank, I have no clue what it's actually doing. Can anyone explain, and are there any other ways to run parameterized tests simultaneously with Spring?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? Do you expect answers here to cover all of JUnit runners, JUnit rules and Spring tests? Voting for the question to be too broad. Be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Any IDE will allow you to jump to the definitions of the SPring rules and debug them. Same for the JUnit Parametrized class.

- A JUnit **Rule** does preparation before and after each method, and before and each after class.
- A JUnit **Runner** does preparation before and after each method, and before and each after class, then runs all methods

Both Spring test rules do the same preparation / cleanup as the Spring Runner would do.

As you can see, rule and runners do mostly the same, the only reason there is a Spring runner is for convenience.

Other ways to run this reasonably would be using JUnit5 or TestNG maybe, instead of JUnit4. Or probably there is a way to setup all spring context in an `@Before` method rather than using annotations.
But really what you have been doing is the recommended way to combine Spring setup with parametrized tests.